# How can i make shuffle in django Forms?

Tags: python, django

I have got a project like quiz. But i need to shuffle the answers in questions.
here is my code:
template.html

```
 <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>{{ current_question.text }}</h3>
    {{ form.selected_answer }}
     <button type="submit">Next</button>
  </form>
```

views.py

```
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = QuestionForm(request.POST, question=current_question)
            if form.is_valid():
                user_answer = form.cleaned_data['selected_answer']
                user_test.useranswer_set.update_or_create(question=current_question,
                                                          defaults={'selected_answer': user_answer})
                return redirect('test', test_id=test_id)
        else:
            form = QuestionForm(question=current_question)
```

There is my django form. I try like this but it doesn't work:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Answer
import random
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet


class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    selected_answer = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Answer.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        empty_label=None
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, question=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if question:
            answers = list(question.answer_set.all())
            random.shuffle(answers)
            self.fields['selected_answer'].queryset = answers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of answers is small, which is likely the case here, you can work with [**`.order_by('?')`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    selected_answer = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Answer.objects.none(), widget=forms.RadioSelect, empty_label=None
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, question=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if question:
            self.fields[
                'selected_answer'
            ].queryset = question.answer_set.order_by('?')
```